# Displaying an updated variable after clicking an action button in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, reactive-programming

I'm new to shiny and trying to accomplish rather a simple task using an action button:

- User clicks a button and a function is called
- This function does some calculations using input variables and updates/creates several global variables (`reactiveValues`, probably inside an `observe` block?)
- I'd like to display those values back on the UI (using `render*` function)
- Whenever user changes input values, the UI is automatically updated

Relevant code bits are:

**server.R**

```
...
rv <- reactiveValues() 
observe({
 if(input$run){
  rv$a <- someFunc(input$aa)
 }
})
output$msg = renderText({ rv$a })
...
```

**ui.R**

```
...
selectInput("aa", ...)
...
actionButton("run", "Run")
...
textOutput("msg")
```

How can I change `msg` based on the input `aa` each time user clicks the button?

Comment: The `...`s in the code aren't very helpful. Try to make a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Describe exactly what you want to change the `msg` value to and how `aa` is involved. I don't really see what the problem is here. What exactly is the behavior you are observing now.

Comment: As far as the code is specified above the renderText already changes the 'msg' in UI.r. Do you want to change the actual wording of the `textOutput` based on the input?

Comment: Any feedback for me?

Comment: @MrFlick Yes, I know, but my code is quite complicated and cannot be reproduced just like that. I appreciate your comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not convinced I understood what you want, but I imagine it to be something like this:

```
library(shiny)
u <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Simple Selectable Reactive Function"),
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        sliderInput("vv", "Choose a value",min=-3.14,max=3.14,value=0),
        selectInput("aa", "Choose a function", choices=c("sin","cos","exp")),
        actionButton("run", "Change Function and Run")
      ),
     mainPanel(
      h2("Results"),
      verbatimTextOutput("msg")
 )))
s <- function(input,output){

  rv <- reactiveValues(func=NULL) 

  observeEvent(input$run,{   rv$func <- input$aa })

  funcval <- reactive({
    v <- 0
    if (rv$func=="sin") v <- sin(input$vv)
    if (rv$func=="cos") v <- cos(input$vv)
    if (rv$func=="exp") v <- exp(input$vv)
    v
  })
  output$msg = renderPrint({
       if (is.null(rv$func)) return("not running")
       fv <- funcval()
       sprintf("%s(%.3f)=%.3f",rv$func,input$vv,fv)
    })
}
shinyApp(ui=u,server=s)
```

Yielding this:

[image]

Note that the slider input value formats its current value rather badly when the min and max values are not even. Not sure what one can do about this.

Comment: I was looking for a simple example and yours nailed it!